# Search and replace with fields on VIM

Tags: regex, vim

I want to search for a string and replace with a second string that was contained in the first one. For example I have the following lines

```
    key1: foo
    key2: bar
```

My regex that maches this lines the way I want is:

```
^\s\+\w:.\+
```

I want to replace the whole lines by something like:

```
foo -> key1
bar -> key2
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vim uses `\1 \2` etc as back references, so you ought to be able to use:

```
:%s/^\s\+\(\w\+\): \(\w\+\)/\2 -> \1/g
```

Breakdown:

- `^\s\+` : one or more spaces at the start of the string. Use `*` if there may be zero
- `\(\w\+\)`: Capture group of word characters into `\1`
- `:` Literal colon and space
- `\(\w\+\)`: Another capture group for the second pair
- `/\2 -> \1/` Replacement with back references. Eliminates the leading whitespace, and swaps the two groups

(here's the `\v` very magic version which will look a lot nicer and avoid tons of meta-character escaping):

```
:%s/\v\s+(\w+): (\w+)/\2 -> \1/g
```

Comment: I think the `foo -> key1` is not the result OP wants, he may want to `replace foo with key1` but not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

I come up with this, `:s` command,

```
 %s/\v\s*([^:]*):\zs.*/\1/
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to substitution

```
:%norm <<dWA -> ^]pbD
```

Note that `^]` is obtained by pressing `<c-v><esc>`

Comment: I think with `:g` would be better.

Comment: @Kent. I can understand that. `:g/\v\s+\w+:\s*\w+/norm <<dWA -> ^]pbD` is a much larger command. I would probably just run the substitution. However it is good to have multiple solutions. Especially when we know so little about text in question.